# pixel space under text in vertical menu ul/li/a

Tags: html, css

I've a simple html ul/li/a vertical menu as this : http://jsfiddle.net/byXED/3/

```
<div id="front_page_a">
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="/">TEXT</a></li> 
        <li class="scostati"><a href="/">TEXT</a></li> 
        <li ><a href="./pages/chi.php"><span>TEXT</span></a></li>
        <li class="scostati"><a href="./pages/dove.php"><span>TEXT</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="./pages/contatti.php"><span>TEXT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is the css i put for the a tag, cause I don't get the right way to have the same space on top and bottom of the text in the anchor tag

```
#pageNavigation {
    background-image: url('../Images/TIBC_Base/nav-bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:5px 15px 5px;
    min-height:125px;
}

#pageNavigation .navContent {
    display: table;
    width:240px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

#pageNavigation .navContent li {
    display: table-row;
    height:57px;
    text-align:center;
}

#pageNavigation a  {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:57px;
    border-top:0px #E1E1E1 solid;
    border-bottom:1px #E1E1E1 solid;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#485963;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px #EEEEEE;
}
```

Please, my question is : why the text of the link ("TEXT") has a space at the bottom ? what I have to do to have the  text vertically centered in the anchor space?
I've tried various way, but none functioned. In the posted example I've put a padding:0px 7px; for the anchor tag but it doesn't work vertically.

The code posted has the problem with Firefox , it works fine with Safari.

Comment: What you mean `("TEXT") has a space at the bottom`? You mean the gap between `red boxes`?

Comment: In the jsfiddle you have `border: 1px solid;` on the anchor tag, this gives the white space between the red blocks, see an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/byXED/4/. And the padding does not work vertically cause you have 0px assigned to the verical value, try with a different number like `padding: 10px 7px;`

Comment: WTF are you using `display: table/table-row/table-cell` for? Don't do that. Stick to block and inline and inline-block. Also, remember the whitespace in between the <li> tags *will often be rendered* and could be the source of any weird space issues you have.

Comment: My problem is not the gap between red boxes. My problem is the gap between the text "TEXT" and the border-bottom line of the anchor tag. I want a zero pixel space  up and down the text in the anchor (exactly I want the sane X pixel space, up and down the text to the border of anchor). That's why I've tried with padding but it not works vertically in the anchor, it not works properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS `a  {` you have a border around the anchor tag and a padding. If you make this values to `0` (zero) your "extra space" disapears.

```
a {
    line-height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:red;
    border: 0px solid; /*changed to zero, removes border*/
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0px 0px; /*changed to zero, removes horiz space before&after text*/
    color:white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: The border is something I've put to put in evidence the problem. See my comment above. The orizontal padding is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that apparently Gecko and WebKit have different interpretations on how line-heights work. This fiddle illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w88Ss/. According to the [definition](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM01/Chap1.html), it seems that Firefox is doing the right thing; anyhow, there is this difference.

[image: font-size]

If you think, for any reason, that you should use this approach, you can try a higher `line-height`, like `line-height:40px`, specifically for firefox, maybe using a JS code.

Comment: Your approach is interesting but I have the impression it seems not the point of the problem. My problem is the pixel space up and down the chars in the anchor tag: i want to center vertically the string in each anchor tag, where the anchor is in a ul/li vertical menu. Taking into account what you say I have inceased the line-height of the anchor to 130% but I have still the same proplem as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/byXED/9/ .

Comment: If you're only thinking about fixing the problem in Firefox, forget about changing `line-height` and just simply add a `padding-top: 3px`, for example, to the end of <a> css definition. Though, it will break what you see in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Kaymar:this is not a solution of the problem but the translation of that problem from Firefox to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, let's say a light workaround, is to use only some font and not some other.

In other words, I've noted that if in the css of the a tag I specify a font like Arial the vertical alignment is perfect with  Firefox & Safari. If I use some other fonts like serif, Helvetica the problem is still there.